# Files in DistributedCache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Do files placed in distributed cache get deleted after job finishes, or I have to do it manually?

I'm guessing that they get deleted, but I'm having some disk issues (The DiskSpace quota of user is exceeded) so I wanted to check.

Also, where do these files get stored and can you check on them using web interface?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538280/re-use-files-in-hadoop-distributed-cache

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov thank you for your link, but could you please clarify the following - What happens in case of hadoop 0.20.2?  Are files deleted when the job finishes, or only when the cache size is overflowed? What happens if I'm given 5GBs on HDFS and cache is setup to 10GBs? Could I get DSQuotaExceededException?